# How to not lose unicode characters in Stored Procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode, parameter-passing

**Problem Statement**:
We are having a legacy application with backend as SQL Server. Till now, we did not face any issues in passing non-unicode values. Now, we are getting unicode characters from user interface.

The unicode character is getting passed as given below, in UI. These  data are being inserted into table.

Currently, we pass unicode characters like below and we are losing non-english characters.

```sql
EXEC dbo.ProcedureName @IN_DELIM_VALS = '삼성~AX~Aland Islands~ALLTest1~Aland Islands~~~~'
```

**What we tried:**
If we pass unicode with N prefix, the non-english characters are being inserted into table properly.

```sql
EXEC dbo.ProcedureName @IN_DELIM_VALS = N'삼성~AX~Aland Islands~ALLTest1~Aland Islands~~~~'
```

But, adding N prefix, requires UI code change. As it is legacy application, we want to avoid UI change.  We want to handle in the sql server side.

when I read about passing parameter without N prefix, the data is implicitly converted to default code page and korean characters are getting lost. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

> Prefix a Unicode character string constants with the letter N to
> signal UCS-2 or UTF-16 input, depending on whether an SC collation is
> used or not. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the
> default code page of the database that may not recognize certain
> characters. Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), when a UTF-8 enabled
> collation is used, the default code page is capable of storing UNICODE
> UTF-8 character set.

**Our Ask:**
Is there a way to add N prefix to the stored procedure parameter, before being assigned to stored procedure parameter and so, we are not losing unicode characters.

Comment: *"But, adding N prefix, requires UI code change. As it is legacy application, we want to avoid UI change. We want to handle in the sql server side."* It shouldn't require a User Interface change, it should require an application code change to use the correct parameter type; clearly your application is passing a `varchar` parameter, or **worse** you are **injecting** a `varchar` literal. Both needs fixing. There is no SQL fix, as once you've use a `varchar` value it's already too late; the data is lost. Fix your application.

Comment: @Larnu, agree with you. we have to fix it at application level. just wanted to see if there is any other tricky workaround to achieve at stored procedure side.

Comment: Strings in most programming are Unicode so, if you specify the value using a a parameter object instead of string literal, you don't need to specify worry about the `N` prefix.

Comment: You have to fix this *regardless* of the Unicode problem. You must **not** inject data into SQL batches, **always** use parameters. There is anyway nothing you can do on the procedure side: it's being passed incorrectly in the first place

Comment: There is indeed a tricky workaround: change the default collation of your database to one that innately supports Korean characters, so `VARCHAR` params can hold them. However, that will do nothing for when the next string comes along with Japanese characters instead, for there are no non-Unicode collations capable of holding every character. Changing the default collation without changing column collations can also easily break other queries, and changing *column* collations is even more involved, so all in all this is not a strategy you want to go for as opposed to fixing your insecure app.

Comment: @Charlieface, agreed. we are going for application code change.

Comment: @DanGuzman, agreed. Yes. We will go for Sqlparameters with NVARCHAR datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not possible to add `N` prefix, after parameter is being passed to SQL Server, we are going with below application code change. Ideally, the application should pass the parameter with right `nvarchar` datatype, so that it is having `N` prefix.

```csharp
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.ProcedureName @IN_DELIM_VALS", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IN_DELIM_VALS", SqlDbType.NVarChar,400)).Value 
  = "삼성~AX~Aland Islands~ALLTest1~Aland Islands~~~~";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```